# How to remove default file input style on IE10?

Tags: css, file, input, styles, internet-explorer-10

Here is my file input on different browsers.
IE10 uses an horrible default style. Any idea about how to remove it?

[image: file input styles]

Comment: Jeez, you're right... That's truly awful.

Comment: Ehhh they all look pretty crappy if you ask me, but at least the chrome one looks like a normal HTML form.

Comment: I just want them to look quite the same. And IE10 doesn't want to. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

IE supports a number of pseudo elements for file inputs:

- [`::-ms-value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465820.aspx) for styling the part where the text is displayed
- [`::-ms-browse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779844.aspx) for styling the button

Using these you can style both parts of the file input however you wish.

Comment: Thanks for this! Able to hide the `::ms-value`, allowing the button to take up the full click area.

Answer (score -2):

Use a reset CSS template (example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

And then style it yourself with your own CSS.

Comment: Then I guess, you'll have to rewrite the CSS yourself?