# on IE 11 Input browse button is not coming with space as in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The input browse button should come as with space on IE11 as it comes in IE8.

See the below images so that you can have a clear idea on my issue.

On IE11, it is coming like this, i mean this is wrong.

[image]

On IE8, it is coming like this, i mean this is right.
[image]

So, i need the same button should come with space in IE 11, Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Every browser uses its own styling for `<input type="file"/>` and it's usually better to just accept that and use the default as there is no standard-compliant solution for styling the upload button (at the moment).

However, if you insist on adding the space, you can use the non-standard `::-ms-browse` selector for targetting the Browse button on the latest IEs.

For example:

```
::-ms-browse {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

(You can use `::-ms-value` for styling the input field part.)

Please have a look at this question: [How to remove default file input style on IE10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618952/how-to-remove-default-file-input-style-on-ie10)

Answer (score 0):

You can't achive changes in IE10 and greater with conditional comments because they were deleted in 10 and 11.

The new workaround is with media queries in css:

Use:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  input (or whatever your selector is) {
      /* your css here */
  }
}
```

For further information regarding css-hacks for IE10 and greater: http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/

Comment: Why are you assuming OP is using conditional comments? It's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @jfrej: the OP isn't, but the other answer, from Benjamin, is using those.

Comment: this workaround affects IE10 and IE11. so it might not be the best choice but i'd assume it's the easiest way to archive what he wants, because both browsers are displaying it wrong (had the same problem some weeks ago).

Answer (score 0):

Its a default browser property so we can't do this